# Installing ASP.Net from "Turn windows features on or off" fails

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-7, iis-7.5, controlpanel

For whatever reason my Visual studio solution no longer loads some projects.

After clicking on the website in IIS I Noticed some configurations no longer present suggesting I needed to install ASP.Net from my control panel using the "Turn Windows features on or off" feature.

After I click on the ASP.Net option under IIS and choose OK I get the dialog 
"An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed"

I noticed that when I go through IIS Manager, under the ISAPI Filters section I see ASP.Net versions

ASP.Net_2.0.50727.0 and ASP.Net_2.0.50727-64

I assume I should be seeing version 4.

Any ideas how this can be fixed would be great.

Going to the Asp.Net4 directory and doing a aspnet_regiis.exe -r does not seem to work for me either as when I go to the websites I am still missing the ASP.Net configuration options.

I have done alot of uninstalls and re installs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have also tried installing ASP.Net form the web installer but that fails to

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you find a solution? Thanks